# SQL Server Sum specific transaction type amounts

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum

I have a temp table (#general) that contains Account number, transaction type, Amount info as below

```
AccountNumber   Tran_Type   Credit
96551AQ6        TSCNYAEUQF  0.0000000
96551AQ6        TSCNYAEUQF  719.0600000
96551AQ6        TSCNYAEUQF  0.0000000
96551AQ6        TSCNYAEUQF  49.4200000
96551AQ6        TSCNYAEUQF  299.0200000
96551AQ6        TSCNYAEUQF  29.6500000
```

I am trying to calculate the percentage of sum of a specific transaction type in total amount by account number.. as in below:

```
select accountnumber,
((select sum(Credit) from #general where Tran_type='INTTRANSINBOUND')*100.0/
(select sum(Credit) from #general)) as percentage
 
  from #general group by accountnumber
```

However, i got same percentage for all account numbers, which is percentage of all, i presume.

What do i do wrong?

Comment: You don't filter on the accountnumber in your subqueries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below using conditional aggregation

```
select accountnumber,
(sum(case when Tran_type='INTTRANSINBOUND' Credit)*100.0)/sum(Credit) as percentage
from #general 
group by accountnumber
```